# Equation to get an ordered logit model from R into Excel

Tags: r, excel, ordered-logit

---

### Original

I have fitted an ordered logistic regression in R using the `polr` function, but I am having some trouble bringing the model coefficients into Excel and getting the probabilities there.

For explanatory variables `FlowMonth2, Orders_Apt, GeoUnits, HomeOwner, Platform, CreditScore`, my coefficients for the model are as follows:

```
                                Value Std. Error  t value
FlowMonth2Aug                 0.12321    0.03852   3.1990
FlowMonth2Dec                 0.31092    0.03854   8.0672
FlowMonth2Feb                 0.02497    0.03873   0.6447
FlowMonth2Jan                -0.01874    0.03940  -0.4757
FlowMonth2Jul                 0.02924    0.03886   0.7525
FlowMonth2Jun                -0.02618    0.04054  -0.6456
FlowMonth2Mar                 0.09369    0.03739   2.5054
FlowMonth2May                -0.08169    0.03581  -2.2811
FlowMonth2Nov                 0.32610    0.03889   8.3841
FlowMonth2Oct                 0.45240    0.03708  12.2009
FlowMonth2Sep                 0.22771    0.04015   5.6711
Orders_Apty                   0.03786    0.02206   1.7160
GeoUnits1                    -0.04070    0.03260  -1.2487
GeoUnits2                     0.11923    0.03735   3.1920
GeoUnitsOther                 0.30464    0.20803   1.4644
GeoUnits5                    -0.19669    0.01892 -10.3942
HomeOwnery                    0.16577    0.02828   5.8624
PlatformMobile               -0.32933    0.01631 -20.1882
CreditScore525 - 600          1.01909    0.02937  34.7036
CreditScore600 - 700          1.12578    0.02953  38.1284
CreditScore700 - 800          1.29098    0.03091  41.7694
CreditScore800 - 900          1.43500    0.03085  46.5179
CreditScore900+               1.33816    0.02851  46.9414
CreditScoreHit with No Score  0.33832    0.03424   9.8812
CreditScoreNo Hit             0.37199    0.06443   5.7737
```

The intercepts are

```
Intercepts:
                Value    Std. Error t value 
0|1              -1.2788   0.0377   -33.9349
1|2              -0.6609   0.0371   -17.8175
2|3              -0.1683   0.0369    -4.5571
3|4               0.1520   0.0369     4.1159
4|5               0.3813   0.0370    10.3163
5|6               0.5615   0.0370    15.1714
6|7               0.7314   0.0371    19.7357
7|8               0.8551   0.0371    23.0486
8|9               0.9608   0.0371    25.8740
9|10              1.0510   0.0372    28.2760
10|11             1.1342   0.0372    30.4826
11|12             1.2607   0.0373    33.8295
12|13             1.4770   0.0374    39.5140
13|14             1.5414   0.0374    41.1957
14|15             1.5827   0.0374    42.2710
15|16             1.6127   0.0375    43.0505
16|Still Active   1.6358   0.0375    43.6499
```

---

Now when I bring this into Excel, I bring in the coefficients, select certain values to add together, say `FlowMonth2 = "Aug", Orders_Apt = "n", GeoUnits = "5", HomeOwner = "y", Platform = "Desktop", CreditScore = "800 - 900"`.

I add these values together to get my logit statistic, $T = \mathbf{x}\mathbf{\beta}$, and then I add this $T$ to each different intercept to get $\beta_{0, i} - T$ for $1 \leq i \leq 17$ where the $17$th stage is transition from 16 to Still Active.

I then take $\mathrm{logit}(\beta_{0, i} - T)$ or ${1 \over 1 + \exp(-[\beta_{0, i} - T])} = \Pr(\text{being in the $i$th stage})$

But when I try to do this in Excel, and compare it to the output of `predict` in R, then I can't get these values to match up? What am I doing wrong in Excel?

---

### Edit

To compare the values from R and Excel, it's by more than a rounding error that they differ:

R:

```
0                                                0.048650293
1                                                0.037989009
2                                                0.047738406
3                                                0.041799312
4                                                0.035787006
5                                                0.031644868
6                                                0.032650167
7                                                0.025400235
8                                                0.022740618
9                                                0.020074660
10                                               0.019006405
11                                               0.029758088
12                                               0.052613086
13                                               0.015949280
14                                               0.010274309
15                                               0.007485204
16                                               0.005777627
Still Active                                     0.514661427
```

Excel:

```
0|1 0.048648622
1|2 0.086640673
2|3 0.134381676
3|4 0.176177948
4|5 0.211958542
5|6 0.243615257
6|7 0.27626595
7|8 0.301669593
8|9 0.32439208
9|10    0.344464821
10|11   0.363487303
11|12   0.393228837
12|13   0.44584823
13|14   0.461809529
14|15   0.472089045
15|16   0.479571379
16|Still Active 0.485339204
```

---

### Edit 2

Why are there only 17 intercepts in Excel, but 18 predicted points in R?

Comment: How badly do the values match up?  I have seen cases where the biggest problems in getting R results and Excel calculations to align are due to the rounding error imposed by just taking the printed coefficients from R (which are much less precise than the values R actually uses to calculate values.)

Comment: @DonDresserLatentView I've added a piece to the question to compare the values, unfortunately it's by more than a rounding error

Comment: @DonDresserLatentView why are there only 17 intercepts in the `summary` of the model in R, but 18 predicted values?

Comment: As far as 17 intercepts vs. 18 predicted values - that is because intercept 1 is used to calculate the probability of result number 1 (which, in your case - is the result with a value of 0) for the first 17 predicted values - and then the probability of result number 18 is just 1-sum(p(r1:r17)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your calculation is figuring the probability not of being in the ith stage - but of being in one of the stages less than or equal to i.  To get the probabilities, subtract the value of the immediately preceding stage.  So - for example

P(1) is your calculated value minus your calculated P(0) value = .0866 - .0486 = .038 - which lines up with the R result to within rounding error.